# Google Docs as Content Management System

Tags: google-docs

I'm thinking of using Google Docs as a content management system, and to integrate it with my java/j2ee web application.
I only need to upload, view, search meta-data, and organize docs.

Would anybody have a reason to believe I should not try this?

Comment: will this be allowed by google?

Comment: what do you mean "allowed", what aspect, accessing via their API?

Comment: their AUP might not look fondly upon this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One good reason not to do that is that then you have no control over your system's uptime.  Google does occasionally have outages, which would take your system down as well.

In addition, by storing them on Google's servers, you are giving up any control over privacy.  There is nothing you can do to ensure Google's security of both their live systems and their backup systems will never be broken, and if they get broken in to, your documents' privacy is lost.  In addition, you'll need to keep an eye on Google's terms of use.  They may very well update it to read "We reserve the right to sell your documents to whomever we please." which may include your competitors.

That being said, if downtime won't break you, and privacy isn't a huge concern, it doesn't sound like a bad idea.  Just make sure they're not the ONLY place you're storing your documents.

Comment: Can you guarantee 100% uptime on your own servers?

Comment: No, but you at least have control over it.